# hasManyThrough relationship in loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I have a `hasManyThrough` releationship in my loopback model. I am trying to follow the Physician/Appointment/Patient example given in the documentation.

[Documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/HasManyThrough-relations.html)

It says at the very end,

> Methods added to the model Once you define a “hasManyThrough”
>   relation, LoopBack adds methods with the relation name to the
>   declaring model class’s prototype automatically, for example:
>   physician.patients.create(...)

One such function is:

> physician.patients(filter,   function(err, patients) {   ... });

I am trying to access this `physician` relation inside a remote method of `Physician` model, but it says `physician` is undefined. In my `Physician` model also, I cannot see a `patients` method. If this is the case, how can I use these methods inside  a remote method?

Comment: Could you add your code maybe you miss something

Comment: Be aware that the methods added by the relationships are instance methods. That is, they can only be invoked in instances of the model and not in the model itself(like find, findOne, etc).